# remove selected style on a DIV

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

I am doing iPhone development and I set a webview with a DIV. I added 'toucstart' 'touchend' 'touchmove' events to this DIV.

But after I added these events, the DIV has a style (look at this video : http://www.bluefly.cn/mask1.swf ) when 'touchstart' (like 'mousedown'), any one knows how to remove this visual effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable tap highlighting, set the [`-webkit-tap-highlight-color`](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-tap-highlight-color) custom CSS property to a colour with an alpha value of `0`:

```
#myElement {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

See [Highlighting Elements](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW5) in the [Safari Web Content Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/) for more information.